# Split widget area with static home page content on a custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am creating my first widget area in a custom theme I am building using this tutorial: http://www.tips4developer.com/wordpress/wordpress-create-custom-widget-area/

This all seems pretty straight forward, but what I want to do is add the widget area only to my static home page, by splitting the content created by the widget area with the home page content I created in Wordpress.  Where would I add the function to show the widget area only on the static home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with the is_page($page_id)

```
 if (is_page($page)){
      // your widget here
}
```

Based on this you can call your static page id with $page

Comment: so if the page name is "Home" then I would replace the $page variable( or define it before the if statement) as $page = "Home"; <br /> Also I add this the the function.php file?

Comment: Yes you need to add this in function.php file.
You can use slug name also like this way
 if (is_page('page-slug'))
or you can use with multiple of page ids's like this
is_page(array('1', '2', '3'))

Comment: Thanks I was actually playing with the array idea as you answered

Answer (score 1):

check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar

If you want to show the side bar in home page only then check it is home page then call side bar for home page like this

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
 get_sidebar('home');
elseif ( is_404() ) :
 get_sidebar('404');
else :
 get_sidebar();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: ok so if I understand the link I create the widget function in my functions.php file then I call it in a file named sidebar-home.php.  then the get_sidebar('home') function the automatically call my widget area?  do I put this if statement in the functions.php file as well?

Comment: Hi you need to put get_sidebar('home') in template where you need to display widget